# Почему includ не работает с глобальными переменными?

Tags: php, include

Почему первая, вторая строки не работаю, а третья работает?

```
include_once($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/connection.php");
include_once($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/connection.php");
include_once("../connection.php");
```

И даже так не работают они:

```
include_once("$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']/connection.php");
```

Скрипт работает из каталога "Soft" (1-ый уровень), a connection.php лежит в корне сайта (0-ой уровень).
В чём тут фикус-пикус?

Comment: А почему вы решили что они вообще должны работать? У вас что, файл `connection.php` действительно нахогдится в каталоге  `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` или `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` относительно текущего пути?

Comment: @klopp Но почему тогда команда `print "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];` показывает `http://www.site_name.ru`?

Comment: Очевидно, потому, что в переменной `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` содержится значение `www.site_name.ru`. Следовательно, конструкции расширяются до `include_once("www.site_name.ru/connection.php")`. А в файловой системе такого пути относительно каталога, из которого инклуды вызываются, просто нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Фикус" тут в том, что "глобальные переменные" надо выбирать не случайным образом, как это делаешь ты, а использовать только те, которые подходят для той или иной задачи.

Теоретически, `HTTP_HOST` и `SERVER_NAME` могут быть использованы для инклюда, но я очень сомневаюсь, что в корне веб-сайта на диске была создана папка с именем сервера. Скорее всего, ты просто путаешь, как все начинающие, файл на диске и НТТР ресурс на сервере. Вот [хорошая статья, которая объясняет разницу](http://phpfaq.ru/paths).

Скорее всего тебе нужен `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, но **сначала ты должен определиться, какой путь тебе вообще нужен**, а потом уже пытаться построить его с помощью переменных.

Если подробно разобрать эти примеры, то, допустим, что сайт у нас лежит в `/home/www/example.com/htdocs`. Тогда первые два примера будут вести в

```
/home/www/example.com/htdocs/Soft/example.com/connection.php
```

в то время как должны вести в

```
/home/www/example.com/htdocs/connection.php
```

при этом в DOCUMENT_ROOT на правильно настроенном сервере должен лежать как раз нужный тебе путь `/home/www/example.com/htdocs` - и вот его и надо подставлять в инклюд.

А третий пример некорректен с синтаксической точки зрения. Если писать внутри двойных кавычек, то можно вот так:

```
include_once("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/connection.php");
include_once("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/connection.php");
```

но я бы предпочел вариант через точку.

Comment: Но ведь print выдаёт в первых двух вариантах это: (б**ть тут Enter запрограммирован по уродски !!!)  
вот это:  
`$http_adr = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];  
print $http_adr; // http://site_name.ru`

Answer (score 1):

Потому что include в php указывает на адрес каталога, а не url страницы как в javascript.
Если в $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] содержится www.example.com, то получаем     `include_once('www.example.com/connection.php')`, что бессмысленно с точки зрения php, вам возможно нужен $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']